# Trigger component action when in view and visible

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview, react-native-scrollview

I am looking to implement a video autoplaying in the listview once user scrolls enough to make the video component visible on screen. However, I cannot find anything in the documentation that could help with implementing an action that would trigger once component is visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [onChangeVisibleRows](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#onchangevisiblerows)